# How can I get a list of unique values for the same field in mongo?

Tags: mongodb

I have a data set like this

```
     {name: john,
      age:20,
      ....
      }
     {name: sally,
      age: 40
      ...
      }
     {name: sally,
      age: 50
      ...
      }
```

What mongo query could I issue to get back every unique value for "name".  So simply it would return 'john' and 'sally'

Comment: use [distinct](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/) like `db.collection.distinct("name")`

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to get every unique value for "name" is by using the **[`distinct()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/)** method on the collection which will query the distinct values for a specified field across a single collection and returns the results in an array. Thus use it as

```
var distinctNames = db.collection.distinct("name");
printjson(distinctNames);
```

**Sample Output:**

```
[ "sally", "john" ]
```

Then another way, though not as simple and straightforward as the above, is to use the aggregation framework where you use the **[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/group/)** pipeline stage to group the documents by the name key and outputs to the next stage a document for each distinct grouping.

With the **[`cursor`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/#cursor-behavior)** returned from the **[`aggregate()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/#db.collection.aggregate)** method, you can then use its **[`map()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.map/#cursor.map)** method to create the desired final array. The following mongo shell demonstration describes the above concept:

```
var distinctNames = db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$name"
        }
    }
]).map(function (r){ return r._id; });
printjson(distinctNames);
```

**Sample Output:**

```
[ "sally", "john" ]
```